# Como fazer um webservice em php?

Tags: php, web-service

Preciso usar pra consultar dados de clientes.

Como faço?

Não tenho experiências em consumir serviços e preciso de referências.

Comment: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/4535/php/construindo-web-services-em-php/

Comment: deu erro no exemplo: "Notice: Undefined variable: HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebServiceSOAP\server.php on line 20
This service does not provide a Web description" como resolvo?

Answer (score 7):

@garssail

Vou te indicar alguns links para estudo que tenho certeza que lhe ajudarão

[Construindo Web Service com php](http://imasters.com.br/artigo/4535/php/construindo-web-services-em-php/)

[Criando um Web Service com php em alguns minutos](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/671437/Creating-Web-Service-Using-PHP-Within-Minutes)

[Introdução JSON e PHP(Web Services)](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/introducao-a-json-e-php-webservices/)

[Manual PHP - Web Services](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/refs.webservice.php)

Nos dois primeiros, vão te explicar como funciona um web service e mostra como criar utilizando SOAP.

No segundo, mostra como trabalhar com o retorno dos WebServices ao retornarem um JSON