# Como enviar input de um app em java para um arquivo php

Tags: php, java

Como enviar input de um app android escrito em java para um arquivo php no server?

O arquivo deve guardar o que o codigo java enviou em uma variável. Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Você vai precisar de um WebService.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Você precisará criar um webservice php para receber esse valor e depois manipulá-lo como desejar. Existe um post que fala sobre isso:

[Como fazer um webservice em php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10102/como-fazer-um-webservice-em-php)

Além disso, é possível encontrar bastante material no google. Sugiro você utilizar o protocolo REST em lugar do SOAP, na construção do seu webservice.